# xlwings How to call macros from PERSONAL.XLS in Excel?

Tags: python, xlwings

I refer to macros that include `xlwings` functionality. I do know how to call the macros, but I've had trouble integrating them with `xlwings` package.  Allow me to explain.

I have included `xlwings` template code in the PERSONAL.XLSB, thus I'm able to call the package.

The first challenge was on adapting the PYTHONPATH to find the `Python Scripts` folder and read the corresponding module.  I did this from within the PERSONAL.XLSB in Visual Basic.

```
-- PYTHONPATH = ThisWorkbook.Path
++ PYTHONPATH = "C:\Users\Diego-MX\Documents\Python Scripts"
```

After several tries to debug my macro, I came to presume that running the macro from a different spreadsheet doesn't capture the Workbook that I intend.  That is `xlwings.Workbook.caller()` inside my macro will refer to `PERSONAL.XLSB` instead of my actual workbook.

Is there a way for me to pass the workbook argument from my spreadsheet, to PERSONAL.XLSB, and then to my `xlwings` macro?

I think this will solve my problem.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to refer to `ActiveWorkbook` instead of `ThisWorkbook` in the xlwings VBA module.

As a side note, there's an add-in planned (see [here](https://github.com/ZoomerAnalytics/xlwings/issues/301)) which will probably also resolve your issue once available.

Comment: Thanks, I really like this tool by the way.  So, to be clear:  You mean the xlwings module in VBA and I am to replace all the `ThisWorkbook` in all Subs and Functions inside it.  There's like 7 of them...